# SQL Sub-Query and Table Joins Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need a help regarding this problem. I tried subqueries but I did not get the results I want.

Theses are my tables:

```
**tblefruitdesc**
 ID       Desc
 1        Round
 2        Smooth
 3        Rough


**tblefruit**
 ID       Name
 1        apple
 2        orange


**tblmultidesc**
ID      fruit_id     fruit_desc
1         1              1
2         2              2
3         2              3
```

I want the output :

```
**tblmultidesc**
     Name         Desc
     Apple        Round
     Orange       Smooth,Rough
```

Comment: What was the best query you tried? Curious ... and please fix the spelling of the Name columns value (case). Hint: For the target (accumulated Desc column) the snippet `group_concat(Desc separator ',')` may come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the three tables together through `tblmultidesc`, and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a comma-separated list of descriptions for each fruit.

```
SELECT t3.Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Desc) AS Desc
FROM tblmultidesc t1
INNER JOIN tblefruitdesc t2
    ON t1.fruit_desc = t2.ID
INNER JOIN tblefruit t3
    ON t1.fruit_id = t3.ID
GROUP BY t3.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.name, c.Desc
FROM tblemultidesc a
LEFT JOIN tblefruit b
ON a.fruit_id = b.ID
LEFT JOIN tblefruitdesc c
ON a.fruit_desc = c.ID
```

Do you actually want to create another table or just display the results?

If you want to create another table that you can reuse over and over just put a CREATE VIEW yourviewname AS the select statement;  Then you will be able to use SELECT * FROM yourviewname as many times as you want without having to write out the SELECT statement.